# Alternatives to NOTIFY that works with prepared transactions

Tags: postgresql-9.2, notify

I've recently discovered that the use of NOTIFY is incompatible with prepared transactions.

Our application writes to a table, that have an AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE trigger, that calls a function trigger, that in turns, calls NOTIFY. A local transaction was used until now. A prepared transaction should be used from now on.

Because I could'nt break existing applications listening to the notification, and because I have no time to rethink of a notification system, I would like to notify weather or not the transaction commits and do that on an alternate connection, straight from the trigger.

Is it only possible ? Do you think of another solution ?

Thanks in advance.